# How to use the 'cases' environment

Tags: math-mode, cases

This code formats

```
|x| = \begin{cases} -x if x less than 0 & \\ xifx greater than or equal to 0 \end{cases}
```

as :

[image]

however to display using greater/less than symbol using code :

```
|x| = \begin{cases} -x if x < 0 & \\ x if >= to 0 \end{cases}
```

is displayed as [image]

How to display 1."-x if x < 0" and 2."x if x >= 0" using latex ?

Comment: Please provide a full MWE. The `&` seems a bit unnecessary to me, and we would normally use `\geq` over `>=` but your code compiles for me in math mode (i.e. between `$...$`)

Comment: @Au101 What is MWE acronym ?

Comment: It's a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) (see link for details) :)

Comment: By the way, your placement of the `&` makes it kinda redundant, but `$|x| =
\begin{cases}
  -x & \text{if } x < 0 \\
  x & \text{if } x \geq 0
\end{cases}$` gives good results

Comment: @Au101 by providing code am I not providing MWE ? btw thanks for your comment

Comment: Well, no, please read the link I provided. Your code compiles for me just fine and doesn't look anything like the output you provided (if I put `$ ... $` around it myself, otherwise, it just gives me an error). This is why it's important for you to provide a **complete** but minimal document. I should be able to select your code, copy and paste it into an editor, save it and compile it exactly as it is without doing anything else and I should get a document.

Comment: So you need to add the preamble that you're using (ideally removing extraneous packages) a `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` and show me how you're entering math mode, because without knowing what else you've done, I can't reproduce your output. I need more information about how you're producing what you're producing. Maybe this is LyX or MathJax. What's your preamble? Are you in an environment like `equation`?

Comment: @Au101 I'm posting a math formula on a wordpress site, wordpress supports latex (more detail : https://en.support.wordpress.com/latex/) so I need to determine how wordpress renders formulas within latex ?

Comment: @blue-sky Also consider providing a MWE as a service to the people willing to help you. If we have a MWE we can just copy&paste it and start solving you problem. With code snippets  we have to type all the necessary stuff like `\documentsclass`, maybe guess which packages are necessary to run the code ...

Comment: @blue-sky Now that's the kind of thing that it's useful to know :) And it makes your lack of preamble, etc. make a lot more sense. It also lets me know I don't really know where the problem lies, 'cause I don't know anything about wordpress, but I do know how to use `cases` in a normal LaTeX document :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot directly enter text in math mode: it will be considered as a succession of variables, in italic with only the very thin spacing in math mode. To enter text, you have to use the  `\text{…}`command. This  requires loading `amsmath`, or `mathtools`, which loads and extends amsmath.

Alternatively, the `cases*` environment from the `mathtools` package can be used, which renders the text after `&` as normal text. You can then use math mode `$ ... $` to have parts of that text rendered as an equation.

The syntax should go like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 
\begin{document}

\[ \lvert x\rvert = \begin{cases*}
                    -x & if  $x < 0$  \\
                     \phantom{-}x & if $x\ge 0$
                 \end{cases*} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, minor typo in your answer, x is missing, should be : " \vert x\rvert = \begin{cases} 
                    -x & \text{if } x < 0  \\
                     x & \text{if } x \ge 0 
                 \end{cases}
"

Comment: Oh! yes. One of my typos. Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: @Mico: Done, my Lord!

Comment: if `\rvert` than `\lvert` instead of `\vert` :-)

Comment: @Zarko: I'm truely inconsistent these days…

Comment: well, very hot summer is here (at least in my place) :-)

Comment: it's often considered good practice to put the entire right-hand side of a line in the case statement in `\text`, as `\text{if $x < 0}`.

Comment: @barbara beeton: OK, I'll replace with the starred extension from `mathtools` (cleaner syntax, from my point of view).

Comment: @barbara beeton: Typo, as usual, milady. 'Twas `\text{if}` before your kind suggestion.

Comment: The last edits made this answer inconsistent (recommending amsmath but using mathtools).

Comment: @Dirk: This is not incompatible as you know… I'll add the necessary information for new users of LaTeX.

Comment: Actually I did not know that mathtools extends amsmath… Thanks!

Comment: What is `\phantom{-}` used for ?

Comment: @FareedAF: It adds the space of a minus sign before the *x*  in the second line, for alignment reasons.

Comment: By the way, regarding `\phantom`, the numcases environment recently eliminated the braces around that column, making it feasible to put `\hfill` (or `\hidewidth`) in the entries to alter justification.